# Change look speed when using PointerLockControls

Tags: three.js, pointerlock

I'm trying out pointer lock in three.js via the examples, but I can't find much information on it.
I'd like to show the user a text field in which they can manually enter their look speed (so the speed of the mouse).

Anyone knows how to do this? Can't seem to find how to increase or decrease the look speed.

In PointerLockControls.js, changing `yawObject.rotation.y -= movementX * 0.002; pitchObject.rotation.x -= movementY * 0.002;` does change the speed, but I can't seem to find how to update it in-game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your copy of `PointerLockControls`. First add

```
this.speedFactor = 0.002;
```

Then modify the lines you referenced like so;

```
euler.y -= movementX * scope.speedFactor;
euler.x -= movementY * scope.speedFactor;
```

Now you can change the look speed dynamically:

```
controls.speedFactor = 0.010;
```

three.js r.120